# How to change a div when a link is clicked and show its content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to change a div in a page and change the content of that div when a link is clicked.I want to do it with angularjs.For example I have 3 links as view1 view2 and view3.These 3 links are inked in to 3 html files view1.html,view2.html and view3.html which contain different contents in each of those files.

When I click the link view1 I need to load view1.html page content in a div.(Dynamically load without changing the other content in the page)and when view2 is clicked view2.html is clicked it should be loaded in to the div.How can I do it?If I use ng-view it will load a whole page.Do I need to use ng-click?If so how can I do it?Please explain..Do I need controllers?If so give me a example :(

Comment: use ng-if & ng-include

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-include` please see demo here
http://plnkr.co/edit/fLIimJZ6GjvQJPU7SWRD?p=preview

```
  <a href="" ng-click="template='view1.html'">View 1</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="template='view2.html'">View 2</a>    
  <a href="" ng-click="template='view3.html'">View 3</a>

  <div ng-include="template"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one of the views to be displayed at one point of time, then use ngSwitch. Details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Otherwise, use ngIf/ngShow to conditionally show views.